# How to collapse and expand menu using uibootstrap and angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

First [image: screenshot]

Second [image: Screenshot]

**Accomplish:** I want to achieve something like this as we can see in the above screenshots and viceversa. For example: Whenever I click on "Search with a list of items" link, then it should work like Second screenshot i.e., the div should be expanded. The div should collapse whenever I click "Search with a list of items" or anywhere outside the div i.e. it should look like First screenshot.

**Issue:**

1. Whenever I click "Search with a list of items" link only the class well of the bootstrap expands and collapse but the other components enclosed within the class well doesn't collapse like textarea,buttons,etc,. and it always remains expanded which you can see in code of plnkr provided.
2. Whenenver I reload/refresh the page, something like Second screenshot always appears during the time of reload/refresh but after the page is completely reloaded/refreshed, it looks like First Screenshot. The need is the page should always appear like First Screenshot whenever the page is reloading/refreshing.
3. Whenever I click anyhwere outside the div, it works like Second Screenshot. The need is whenever I click anywhere outside the div, it should work like First Screenshot i.e., it should collapse.

`Here is my plnkr:` [Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/JaIoV86zJydBUo5T3oi3?p=preview)

Comment: anyone willing to contribute???

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do in this way. Please check it. May helpful for you. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Comment: Please explain your answer too.